# How can I make month/year drop down layout like in material 3 documentation?

Tags: android, material-design

I found [this component](https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/specs) while searching material3 website in specs section, and want to implement it the same way, but couldn't find the layout in the library.

Is there a way to do it?

[image: date picker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of date picker currently not available for Material-Android version; There is no (XML Layout) for that yet. If you're interested in the latest updates, you can follow this [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3048).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for layout.

If you have not refere [material component git](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/DatePicker.md) then please do once.

[Java source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.java)

Comment: all of these are date picker dialogs. I want a drop down picker like the image attached

Comment: ok, I have misunderstood the question.